# Interpolating a constantly changing value

Tags: javascript, interpolation

I understand how to interpolate a value between two values based on an amount (time for instance).

So for any given interpolation function I can perform the following actions:

- Start animation, start a timer, t (1 second for ease)
- Every loop increase t by dt
- Measure position of object as lerp(startPos, endPos, t)

My question is, how do I handle interpolation like this on a continuous basis when the start and end position might be changing all the time (similar to how CSS transitions work)

If I update the variables everytime I get a new destination the animation will seem to stall as the velocity of the transition is brought back down to zero.

Comment: You can't do that. But you can give a bezier curve that would match the motion function graph that you want to achieve.

Comment: This is quite broad. What would you want to happen if the animation is halfway, and the endPos is suddenly moved to the current position of the object? Should the animation stop? Should the animation continue with object moving away from the target position for a while?